# POST files using HTTP action - encoding problems

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have problems to upload attachments to JIRA REST API using HTTP POST with the HTTP action. It works with text files (Content-Type: text/plain) but when I'm posting other files such as PDF and images the files are not uploaded correctly; they get the wrong file size and are not readable.
I assume it's a problem with the encoding. I've tried to use the binary function on the file contents but it does not help. According to JIRA the REST API doesn't accept base64-encoded files.

Have anyone of you been successful in posting attachments (other than text files) to JIRA or another API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. The body of the HTTP request should contain special attributes for Multipart and Content-Type as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#content-with-multipartform-data-type

So the HTTP POST should look like this:
[image]